# Windows 10 not booting 80004001 error code

Tags: windows-10, boot

I've got some issue here.

**Configuration:**
I have Lenovo Ideapad 700-15ISK (SSD). Windows 10 (Home, I believe).

**Issue description:**
One day, I uninstalled one of thousands Lenovo software, windows restarted, I needed to choose keyboard layout and then got 2 options:

1. Troubleshoot
2. Turn off your PC
   No error messages.

Then I discovered: If press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get following message:

```
Restart your PC to try again
It looks like something didn't load correctly. Restarting might fix the problem. If this happens more than once, you might also be able to find help ...
**Error code: 8004001**
```

I restart and get the same screen.

If I go to "Troubleshoot" then I get 6 following options:

1. System restore
2. Go back to previous version
3. System Image Recovery
4. Startup Repair
5. Command Prompt
6. UEFI firmware Settings

**Troubleshooting steps done:**

1. If I press system restore I get "to use system restore, you must specify which windows installation to restore...". When I specify the "windows installation" via command prompt `rstrui.exe /OFFLINE:C\Windows` and restore to previous point (before I uninstalled that lenovo software), then nothing happens - I just restart and come to same situation.
2. I created bootable USB (installed ISO from windows website and created bootable USB that is compatible with UEFI, FAT32). In bios I turned "enable" next to boot from USB, but still nothing happens when I restart PC. I try to choose an option to via "System Image Recovery (4.)", but it says: "Windows cannot find a system image on this computer". I click "advanced">"install a driver", choose "autorun.setup information" and it says: "the specified location does not contain information about your hardware". I hit cancel and go cry in my bedroom
3. Startup repair doesn't help
4. Go back to previous version says: we ran into a problem and won't be able to take you back to the previous versions of windows. TRy resetting your PC instead(bro, I am trying)"

Tried to run some random commands in command prompt as well (bootrec /fixmbr /fixboot /scanos /rebuildbcd)

When I open command prompt I have "X:\windows\system32>"
I can clearly see my drives and look through files via system image recovery (can't open them though)

I believe it may be caused by lack of some drivers. Like nothing is wrong, but windows can not understand that he needs to boot from disk C.

**GOAL:**
Make my PC work again. No data needed to be saved (would be nice if I can save it, but not so important). 
P.S. I know there might be too many details, but it's just to avoid unnecessary questions.

Comment: UPD: My device was service before and they "updated BIOS", as they said. PC was slower than before service (FPS in games dropped from 60 to 15 or smth) and that was the main reason for me to update drivers and delete unwanted software. I am not sure if it is related, but let it be here.

Comment: Maybe the best solution would be to return the computer to the people that created these problems.